# Different result in different pdf viewer pdfsharp

Tags: c#, pdf

Me and my team recently changed from ITextSharp to PdfSharp, because of ITextSharp became really slow, and we couldn't seem to fix the problem.

But right now we have a problem, where our pdf, thats filled by PdfSharp, is 200kb bigger then the one from ITextSharp. The size itself isn't the problem, its that when we open our pdf in firefox, the data is still displayed fine in the viewer, but when we want to print it, all the multiline fields, is suddenly one liners, with a different font too.

We have `/NeedAppearance` on our acroform elements, and tried to remove it to see what it would look like in adobe, and etc. and it looked the same as it did on the print screen in firefox.

The `NeedAppearance` isn't on our document from the ITextSharp, and it displays fine in every viewer.

This is the code we use to set the text:

```
public static bool SetField(this PdfAcroForm form, string fieldName, string value)
{
        PdfTextField field = (PdfTextField)form.Fields[fieldName];

        if (field != null)
        {
            field.Text = value;
        }

        return field != null;
}
```

At the end of the fields being set, we have a `document.flatten()` to make the fields readOnly.

**A little side note**

Once we have opened the pdf in adobe, and we want to close it, it wants us to save it, without we have changed the document. Once we have saved it, it is 200kb less, and suddenly works in all viewers. This is with `/NeedAppearance` on.

**Update 1**

I've spend the whole night looking for a solution, but couldn't.
But this is what I have found so far:

- On every `PdfTextField` after the `Text` property has been set, there comes an `/AP` element in `Elements` which contains a reference to an object, which contains what should be drawn.

I think that Adobe can understand the `/NeedAppearance` element on the acroforms, and therefore makes the `/AP`element on every field correct. The reason for the file is less kb after, is seams to be that Adobe do something with the streams on the elements, some sort of encoding, that takes off less space.

So as it is right now, I think I have too create a new Flatten method that creates the `/AP` elements right. I don't know why The current `Flatten` method doesn't do that, as it's only changing the fields to readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, is to create my own flatten method.

Summary of what the Flatten method do:

I've mad it an extension to `PdfAcroForm`.

I loop trough all the fields, except `PdfChecboxfield`, because that is displayed just fine.
Then I went and found the page the field was on, and created and `XGraphics` from that page.

Then I get the position and size of the field, from the element `/Rect`

Then putted my `XGraphics` in a `XTextFormatter`, and sets the appearance on my `XTextFormmater` by the elements of my field.

Then I use `XTextFormatter.Drawstring()` and after that, dispose my `XGraphics`.

Then to remove the field, I delete all the elements on that field.

If this was unclear to you, feel free to comment, and I'll try my best to help you.

**DISCLAIMER:**

The flatten method I created, will delete your fields, and you **CAN NOT** undo it. It writes the text on the pdf itself, but just do it on the fields position.